# All of my scripts in GEE code editor have disappeared

Tags: google-earth-engine

I signed into GEE code editor today to find that all of the scripts I've written and saved are now gone. It just says "No accessible repositories" under owner/writer/reader drop down panel. All of my assets are still there though. I do use a government email address to sign in if that matters.

Is there anything I can try to get them back?

Comment: Mine say the same thing, GEE repository serving must be down right now?

Comment: The issue that prevented the display of the script repositories has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GEE developer's forum:

[image]

From further down the thread:

"I strongly advise against creating a new repo at this time, especially one with the same name as your old one. It's quite possible that could overwrite the old one."